# How to debug windows phone 8 deadlocks on HTC 8x

Tags: htc-8x

Question is pretty self-explanatory.  I did not see anything relevant in web search results.  Could you point me at some tutorials?

Details:  My phone locks up at random, during various workflows.  If I leave the phone in locked-up state for 5-10 minutes, it reboots all by itself, probably with a watchdog.  I have contacted T-Mobile, and they promised a replacement.  I am a software dev, so I'd like a stab at debugging this issue before reaching for a hardware solution.

Comment: Have you tried doing a factory reset? I don't think there is much you can do to diagnose it yourself.

Comment: Whilst I've not got an 8x, I have seen similar issues with other HTC devices (HTC Diamond, HTC TyTn) - I've not seen it with the Nokia Lumia though...

Comment: There is no good way to remove the battery.  I let the phone battery drain to empty overnight.  Let's see if stability improves today.  I am stalling before sending the phone back to T-Mobile in fear of receiving a refurb in place of a new phone.  I'll report back.

Comment: Still locks up after I pressed power button for 10 seconds to reset.  I am trying the vol-down + power button way to shut down and restart.  Will keep you posted.

Comment: This leads me to believe I won't have luck with replacement phone: http://essayboard.com/2012/12/13/htc-8x-locked-up-screen-died-but-soft-reset-brought-it-back-to-life/

Comment: MS support says to relax and to let OEM handle this issue.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wptools/thread/b77713ec-4dc2-45de-b561-505a56f1f4db/

Comment: Whilst it does not debug your issue. The holding the volume down and the power button for 10 seconds will restart the phone. Upon restart you might be able to find the feedback file on the phone.

Comment: I used HTC repair facilities.  All is well for a couple of months; but I have no idea what was done, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for you to debug or get any extra information about the operating system crashing.

I would suggest turning on the feedback option under settings->system->feedback, this way Microsoft has a chance of getting some information about the crash.

Comment: "Your phone has sent 0.27MB of feedback data in the past 7 days."  There is a download waiting for me under phone update.

Comment: "Your phone has sent 0.39MB of feedback data in the past 7 days."